# Is it possible to switch Gutenberg's editor styles when document settings change?

Tags: hooks, block-editor, admin-css

I want to show different editor styles based on one of the post's value in the `core/editor` store. Let's say, for example, that I've got a setting like, `picture_frame` in my post meta, that adds gimicky "picture frame" border around all of the content in the post. (Ignore whether this is a good or bad idea, it's just an example). On the front end, I use `the_content` filter to add the classes I need for CSS. But in Gutenberg, I'm not sure what filter to use. If I dispatch an action to change that value in the editor, like this;

```
dispatch('core/editor').editPost({
  meta: { _picture_frame: true },
});
```

I want the styles in the editor to change accordingly. Either by adding a `.has-picture-frame` class to a parent element, or enqueueing a `picture-frame-styles.css` stylesheet. But I can't figure out the correct filter for either modifying the editor's classes, or changing which stylesheets are enqueued.